# plugin_action_links Filter Hook Deprecated?

Tags: plugins, filters

[http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/plugin_action_links_%7B$plugin_file%7D](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/plugin_action_links_%7B%24plugin_file%7D)

Says the hook is deprecated.  However, the [{$prefix}plugin_action_hook_{$plugin_file}](http://mobile.adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/%7B%24prefix%7Dplugin_action_links_%7B%24plugin_file%7D) is not.  I poked around the `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugins-list-table.php` file for the hook, and found this:

```
$actions = apply_filters( $prefix . "plugin_action_links_$plugin_file", $actions, $plugin_file, $plugin_data, $context );
```

`$prefix` is defined a few lines above:

```
$prefix = $screen->is_network ? 'network_admin_' : '';
```

Since I was able to get my add_filter call to `plugin_actions_row_{$plugin_file}` to work, I'm assuming the filter hook is still there. Well, sort of: the filter is still available as it's not a network admin screen.  Correct? And one could use...

```
add_filter( 'network_admin_plugin_action_links_{$plugin_file}', 'do_something' )
```

...to put a link into the network's plugin screen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, both should work as expected:

`"plugin_action_links_{$plugin_file}"`

`"network_admin_plugin_action_links_{$plugin_file}"`

Note that I'm using `"` instead of `'`.

PS: The term is *deprecated*, not depreciated.

Comment: "The term is deprecated, not depreciated" Phew, I thought the filter had lost value ;)

Comment: Whoa, I've been misreading that one for a long time now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should be backward compatible and error free

```
"{$prefix}plugin_action_links_{$plugin_file}"
```

Comment: This answer would greatly increase in quality if you made it clear as to how it's different from the original answer. Also, what is `$prefix`?

Comment: Tough to answer that. It's been a long time. The main difference is `{$prefix}` but it seems the author of the question has answered that. It removes the warning from wordpress in debug mode and makes the program work even if $prefix is changed to something else other than ''.

You have to understand that this hook isn't a part of the official wordpress api so it's best to hook into it the same way native wordpress code does so your code won't have issues in the future.